# Disable a group of input elements at once

Tags: php, html, css

I need to disable a group of input elements without having to set the disabled attribute in each of them. Since in my case, these elements are all inside a table's row, I thought to put the attribute in the container tr, but as far as I know, only input elements support it. I would like to be able to do something like:

```
<table>
    <tr disabled="disabled">
        <td><input name="i1" type="checkbox" .../></td>
        <td><input name="i2" type="text" .../></td>
            ...
        <td><input name="iN" type="text" .../></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and have every input from i1 to iN disabled.
How can I achieve the same result, maybe using CSS or some other approach?

Comment: The only way I can think of to do this would be to use Javascript. Is that an option for you?

Comment: I agree, there is no "nice" way to do this in CSS. I would use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable through CSS.

---

You can achieve it through javascript (like in Dryden Long answer). Disabling all *input* of the *tr* in question.

But that has the problem of not being disabled when rendered. That means there will always be a moment where the inputs are not disabled. Be reminded of that.

---

I don't know how do you create those *input*.
But, for example, if they are produced through PHP you can specify that on your loop.

And even if you don't, if you can use PHP on your server, that could make things easier.
It is as simple as doing this:

```
<table>
    <tr disabled="disabled">
        <td><input name="i1" type="checkbox" .../></td>
<?php
  for ($i=2;$i<$n;$i++)
        echo '<td><input name="i'.$i.'" type="text" disabled="disabled" .../></td>';
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you have different types you can always do something like:

```
<table>
    <tr disabled="disabled">
<?php
  $arr = array("checkbox","text","text"...);
  for ($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
        echo '<td><input name="i'.($i+1).'" type="'.$arr[$i].'" disabled="disabled" .../></td>';
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And if you want to avoid equal strings you can create a second array to store the different possible values. Like this:

```
<table>
    <tr disabled="disabled">
<?php
  $arr1 = array(0,1,1,1,0,1...);
  $arr2 = array("checkbox","text");
  for ($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
        echo '<td><input name="i'.($i+1).'" type="'.$arr2[$arr1[$i]].'" disabled="disabled" .../></td>';
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, in fact I'm using PHP to generate them. But it doesn't happen inside a loop, since they are all different. Precisely I specified different types in them (checkbox in the first, text in the second) to highlight that. I know I can set echo the disabled attribute from PHP, but I have to do it explicitly for each input, and that's what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: You can create a variable $dis = 'disabled="disabled"' and concatenate in each.
Or you can create an array with the type and name of each input and a loop that cycles through them all.

Comment: I added to the answer how you can use arrays to store the different types of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Javascript, something like this will do the trick:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Or if you're using jQuery, this approach is probably simpler:

```
$("input").prop("disabled", true);
```

If you can't use Javascript, then the only thing I could think of would be to hide the `<input>` tags using CSS, but this won't truly disable them, only hide them from view. So, if any of the inputs have default values, those values will still get passed.

```
input {
  display: none;
}
```

All things equal, I definitely recommend using the Javascript or jQuery method.

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)

`$('.disabled input').attr('disabled','disabled');`

This would disable all input elements under your disabled row.